# Parse Json Encode Array PHP error

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, parsing

Here is my problem :

I have a PHP file, that should return multiple records,
everything worked fine... but, i don't know why, probably because of a little mistake somewhere... now it doesn't work anymore...

my Json_encode(my php) returns this :

```
{"1":{"id":"2222","name":"ERESRS"},"2":{"id":"1111","name":"LJLJM"}}
```

instead of simply :

```
[{"id":"2222","name":"ERESRS"},{"id":"1111","name":"LJLJM"}]
```

anybody had this issue before?

i already checked again and again my php file, and i don't find where this "false array" comes from...

thanks for help

Here is the js code :

```
$.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : './php/getBenefListe.php',
                    data : {'id':idSoc},
                    error : function(){
                        alert('ERREUR MISE A JOUR DE LA LISTE');
                    },
                    success : function(response){
                        $("#benefListe").empty();
                        $('#benefListe').append($('<option>',{
                            value : '',
                            text : 'Choisissez dans la liste'
                        }));
                        alert("REPONSE : "+response);
                        var myData = JSON.parse(response);
                        for(var i=0;i<myData.length;i++){
                            var id = myData[i].id;
                            if(id-latestBenef > 0){
                                latestBenef = id;
                            }
                            var nom = myData[i].nom;
                            var prenom = myData[i].prenom;
                            var rue = myData[i].rue;
                            var numero = myData[i].num;
                            var boite = myData[i].bte;
                            var cp = myData[i].cp;
                            var loc = myData[i].loc;
                            if(rue!="" && numero!=""){
                                rue = rue+", "+numero;
                            }
                            if(cp!="" && loc!=""){
                                loc = "- "+cp+" "+loc;
                            }
                            var field = nom+" "+prenom+" ; "+rue+" "+boite+" "+loc;
                            $('#benefListe').append($('<option>',{
                                value : id,
                                text : field
                            }));
                        }
                        alert("B\351n\351ficiaire Ajout\351!");
                        $("#benefListe option[value="+latestBenef+"]").prop('selected',true);
                        $("#benefListe").change();
                    }
                });
```

here is the php file called :

```
include "./functions.php";
if(isset($_POST['id']) && ($_POST['id']!='')){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $db = connectToDb('test');
    $myArray = array();
    $i = 0;
    $getBenefIds = "SELECT DISTINCT IDPERSONNE FROM socrsp WHERE (IDSOCIETE = $id);";
    $benefIds = $db->prepare($getBenefIds);
    $benefIds->execute();
    $count = $benefIds->rowCount();
    if($count>0){
        foreach($benefIds as $benefId){
            $getBenef = "SELECT IDPERSONNE,NOM,PRENOM,ADRESSE,NUMERO,BTE,IDCOPOSTAL,CODEPAYS FROM personne WHERE IDPERSONNE = ".$benefId['IDPERSONNE'];
            $myBenef = $db->prepare($getBenef);
            $myBenef->execute();
            foreach($myBenef as $benef){
                if(!(is_numeric($benef['ADRESSE']))){
                    $myArray[$i]['id'] = $benef['IDPERSONNE'];
                    $myArray[$i]['nom'] = $benef['NOM'];
                    $myArray[$i]['prenom'] = $benef['PRENOM'];
                    $myArray[$i]['rue'] = '';
                    $myArray[$i]['num'] = '';

                    $myArray[$i]['rue'] = $benef['ADRESSE'];
                    $myArray[$i]['num'] = $benef['NUMERO'];
                    $myArray[$i]['bte'] = $benef['BTE'];

                    //RECUP CP ET LOCALITE
                    if((isset($benef['IDCOPOSTAL']) && ($benef['IDCOPOSTAL']!='0') && ($benef['IDCOPOSTAL']!='2913'))&&($benef['CODEPAYS']=="B")){
                        $whereQuery = "SELECT CODEPOSTAL,LIBLOCALITE FROM copostal WHERE IDCOPOSTAL = ".$benef['IDCOPOSTAL'];
                        $where = $db->prepare($whereQuery);
                        $where->execute();
                        foreach($where as $w){
                            $myArray[$i]['cp'] = $w['CODEPOSTAL'];
                            $myArray[$i]['loc'] = $w['LIBLOCALITE'];
                        }
                    }else if((isset($benef['IDCOPOSTAL']) && ($benef['IDCOPOSTAL']!='0'))&&($benef['CODEPAYS']!="B")){
                        $whereQuery = "SELECT CPEXTERNE,LOCEXTERNE FROM cpostext WHERE IDCPOSTEXT = ".$benef['IDCOPOSTAL'];
                        $where = $db->prepare($whereQuery);
                        $where->execute();
                        foreach($where as $w){
                            $myArray[$i]['cp'] = $w['CPEXTERNE'];
                            $myArray[$i]['loc'] = $w['LOCEXTERNE'];
                        }
                    }else{
                        $myArray[$i]['cp'] = '';
                        $myArray[$i]['loc'] = '';
                    }
                    $i++;
                }else{
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($myArray);
    $db = null;
}
```

Comment: Please post your php code...we are coders, not magicians xD

Comment: this is it, magician ;D

Comment: Have you tried `json_encode(array_values($array))`?

Comment: Please pos the output of `var_dump($myArray);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're setting manually the `keys` for the PHP array or editing it in some way. Compare the following results:

```
<?php

$a = ['hello', 'world'];
echo json_encode($a);
// ["hello","world"]

$b = [1 => 'hello', 2 => 'world'];
echo json_encode($b);
// {"1":"hello","2":"world"}

$b = ['hello', 'world', 'how', 'are', 'you'];
unset($b[2]);
echo json_encode($b);
// {"0":"hello","1":"world","3":"are","4":"you"}
```

As @amphetamachine suggest, a possible solution is this:

```
$b = [1 => 'hello', 2 => 'world'];
$b = array_values($b);
echo json_encode($b);
// ["hello","world"]
```

Another interesting test (your case):

```
<?php

$a = $b = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
  $a[$i] = "test";
  if ($i != 1) {
    $b[$i] = "test";
    }
  }

echo json_encode($a);
// ["test","test","test"]

echo json_encode($b);
// {"0":"test","2":"test"}

echo json_encode(array_values($b));
// ["test","test"]
```

From which, we can get that you *do need* that `array_values()` if you want to set not-consecutive array keys.

Comment: well... i just realized that the problem does not ALWAYS happen...!!

Comment: No, it will only happen when, in some case, you do not enter this if: `if(!(is_numeric($benef['ADRESSE'])))` and thus there's non-consecutive keys

Comment: i don't get it... why does this json encodes my data with numeric keys like this? my data is there, these are not empty records...

Comment: The same code, in some cases gives me that : 
    RETURNDATA : [{"id":"221","nom":"test","prenom":"testtest","rue":"rue testttt","num":"12","bte":"","cp":"5000","loc":"TTDDD"}]

and for another id sent in the post, gives me this : 
    RETURNDATA : {"1":{"id":"227","nom":"qdfqsdfqs","prenom":"qsfqs","rue":"qsdfqsdfqsdf","num":"11","bte":"","cp":"4444","loc":"LUXVILLE"},"2":{"id":"228","nom":"benef2","prenom":"","rue":"rueeeee","num":"11","bte":"","cp":"5555","loc":"LUXLUX"}}

:'(

Comment: Indeed it is. In your example, `{"1":{"id":"2222","name":"ERESRS"},"2":{"id":"1111","name":"LJLJM"}}` has no record for "0", so that record is not returned (thus, empty). If the `$benef['ADRESSE']` is not numeric, then that array element is never set and the key for that element is empty in `$myArray`.

Comment: O...M...F...*... !!!!! you're awesome... the problem was only that else {$i++;} that i had to remove... didn't think about that before... thanks a lot for your help and patience... ;p

Comment: You're welcome. For the future try flattening more the structure (not so many anidated `if`s) so you can see the problem more clear and write some error-checking code (;

Comment: well, i try to do my best with the time i have for doing this... but sure, my code is not what i'd call a "proper" code... but i think in this case that i "need" these "ifs"... thx again :)